# What is the difference between += and =+ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am just learning Ruby and I want to know the difference between

```
a += b
```

and

```
a =+ b
```

Comment: It makes sense, because it is a beginner question.  At a guess, the asker saw this in someone else's code (which is why smartypants, non-standard code is rarely a good idea!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `a += b` is syntactic shorthand for `a = a + b`
2. `a =+ b` is similar to `a = + b`

So, `firstValue = firstValue + secondValue` is the same as `firstValue = firstValue.+(secondValue)` in ruby.
**`firstValue + = secondValue` – increment** Add the value of `secondValue` to the value of `firstValue` , store the result in `firstValue`, and return the new value.

Answer (score 4):

- `foo += bar` is shorthand for `foo = foo + bar`.
- `foo =+ bar` is an unusual way to write `foo = +bar`.

Comment: It’s worth to mention that for the latter to work, the `+@` instance method should be defined on `bar.class`. For the former, the coercion from `bar.class` to `foo.class` is required.

Comment: An actual use case: if `bar` is a frozen string, then `foo = +bar` becomes a shorthand for `foo = bar.dup`, i.e. it assigns a mutable duplicate of the string to `foo`.